# iOS UINavigationController PushViewController is not working

Tags: iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have use one class and this class super class is UIView class in that i can push to other viewcontroller using pushviewcontroller

.h File

```
@class AppDelegate;

@interface BarButton : UIView  
{

      AppDelegate *appDelegate;

}

@property(retain,nonatomic)AppDelegate *appDelegaet;
```

.m File

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

-(IBAction)btn4Click:(id)sender

{

    OrderViewController *orderView=[[OrderViewController alloc] 
       initWithNibName:@"OrderViewController" bundle:nil];
    [appDelegate.navObj.navigationController pushViewController:orderView animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: what is navObj in AppDelegate class. Let me know its type or class.

Comment: i can use custom class and that class super class is UIView class in this class i can push to other view controller code

Comment: navObj is UINavigationcontroller object that can declare in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your this line of code

```
[appDelegate.navObj.navigationController pushViewController:orderView animated:YES];
```

to

```
[appDelegate.navObj pushViewController:orderView animated:YES];
```

Comment: you can accept this answer if you found it correct!! Enjoy coding!!